# Awaiting code execution in quasar.dev boot file before vue.js instantiation

Tags: vue.js, async-await, quasar-framework

The quasar.dev framework introduces the concept of boot files: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
Using the vue-oidc-client, I am required to wait for the `oidc.startup()` call *before* the Vue instance is created (see https://github.com/soukoku/vue-oidc-client/wiki#app-start)

Since I can't simply put an `await` outside of an `async` function, I am wondering how I can achieve this.

My code as reference:

```
// Importing stuff and creating 'oidc' with createOidcAuth(...)

const startupSucessful = oidc.startup()
if(!startupSucessful) throw Error("Unable to bootstrap OIDC client");

export default boot(async ({ app, router, Vue }) => {
  oidc.useRouter(router);
});
```

Comment: *before the Vue instance is created* - boot function runs before it's created and suits the description. Did you try `await oidc.startup()`?

Comment: @EstusFlask I can't `await` outside of an `async` function.

Comment: You shouldn't. await inside of it. To my understanding, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Since your export block is async, just put the code you want to wait for there:

```
export default async ({ app, router, Vue }) => {
  
  const startupSucessful = await oidc.startup()
  
  if(!startupSucessful) 
    throw Error("Unable to bootstrap OIDC client");
  else
    oidc.useRouter(router);
  
});
```